# Athena SPLIT_PART last element

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have no normalised fields in a no-sql json extract queried from ATHENA.

I would like to get the last value of my field.

fields examples:

```
Raleigh, NC, USA
Frankfurt, Germany
```

In the idea i would like something like this to select last element:

```sql
SPLIT_PART(city, ',' , last_element ) AS country
```

I don't know if i use the right function to perform this.

Bonus: how to select a field with like value.from without raise sql error ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract()`:

```
select regexp_extract(city, '[^ ,]+$')
```

This returns the last set of strings in `city` that do not contain spaces or commas -- the last element you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If instead of `split_part()`, you use `split()` and `element_at()` functions of AWS Athena combined together, you would get the desired result.

```
ELEMENT_AT(SPLIT(city, ','),-1) AS country
```

For further reference on `element_at()` function follow this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/accessing-array-elements.html).
For further reference on `split()` function follow this [doc](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html).